# How to deploy Sitecore 7.2 Using Azure Web Apps

Tags: azure

I am planning to move existing Sitecore 7.2 website into azure. I have read several blogs and most of them are about cloud service. Can we deploy Sitecore 7.2 using Azure Web App service?

Any consideration we need to take in account?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not officially supported, but I can tell you that it does work :)

There are some circumstances with scaling the system to multiple instances that can run into trouble based on the way that the instances share file-system resources (Lucene doesn't like that) but if you have Solr - which you should on any scale-out model anyway - it should be ok.

We've run 7.2, 7.5, and 8 on Web Apps for ages without any specific issues that we're aware of.  Just be aware, since it is not officially supported, if you run into an issue and you contact support about it, they may not be willing to fix it.

FWIW, since your Sitecore licenses probably only entitle you to a fixed number of CD servers, there's little advantage to using Web Apps anyway.  They are almost exactly the same price as VMs.

Answer (score 0):

As Richard said, Sitecore doesn't officially support [Azure App Service](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/app-service/web/) (Web Apps) yet, but you can run Sitecore on it with some caveats.

Check this article:

- https://github.com/olegburov/Sitecore-Azure-Content/blob/master/articles/how-to-deploy-sitecore-81-solution-to-microsoft-azure-web-app-using-visual-studio.md

I would recommend start looking to version 8.2 of Sitecore XP, where Azure Web Apps support is coming.